# gWidgets GUI cannot display when called with R CMD BATCH

Tags: r, user-interface, gwidgets

I developed an analyzer with GUI (utilizing gWidgets package). Everything seems good when I run my code in R console or R studio, GUI can popup as expected, interaction goes smoothly by choosing options.

However, my manager has no idea about coding stuff, and what he wants is click-N-run. So I tried to use `R CMD BATCH` to create `.bat` file.

> > R CMD BATCH  G:\Temp\dav\AB_Analyzer\MAINcode.r outputFile

When I ran the bat file, there is nothing popping up.

May I know what I did wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would think this has something to do with the fact that R CMD BATCH will  *Run R non-interactively with input from infile and send output (stdout/stderr) to another file*.  (as per the help file!)

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to have a click-n-run shortcut?

Comment: Ok, it seems that R CMD BATCH doesn't work for interactive GUI. I got another way, credit to the genius
http://drunks-and-lampposts.com/2012/06/18/r-creating-a-shortcut-to-run-a-gwidgets-gui/

Answer (score 1):

If you run an R script in batch mode (`R CMD BATCH`) the "interactive flag" is set to `false` which may trigger this behaviour (no user interaction = do not show any GUI).

You can query the "interactive flag" with the `interactive()` function in R.

Possible solution: Add the `--interactive` parameter to the command line.

To test his behaviour create an R script file with the following content:

```
print(interactive())
```

If you run this script with

```
R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore  batch_test.R out.txt
```

You will find the result `FALSE` in the out.txt file, if you run it with

```
R --vanilla --interactive  < batch_test.R
```

You will see a `TRUE` (so use the last command line as solution - note: **without CMD**).

Comment: Thank you for this. That last line is the only way I could get this to work for me, despite trying it many different ways from various answers here and elsewhere. I don't fully understand why, even after reading the help pages - but I'm glad it does! The only variation I had to use was switching `--interactive` to `--ess` as I'm on Windows. Then it works perfectly if you specifically call R.exe or Rterm.exe, but *not* RScript.exe.

Comment: Thanks for point out the command line arg for Windows (which seems to lack the `--interactive` arg but `--ess` looks good (ess = don't use getline for command-line editing and assert interactive use").