# How to get dialog/message box working in executable R file

Tags: r, user-interface, executable

I have an executable `R` file. All of the code works as expected, except for the function `winDialog()`, which works through `RStudio`, but not when the file is run through double clicking.

The code in question is as follows:

```
winDialog("ok", paste0("The checks have been completed in ", round(as.numeric(time.taken), digits = 2), " minutes."))
```

`time.taken` exists as a variable, so that is not the problem.

Is there a different function that would work?

**Edit:** My question is similar to this one: [gWidgets GUI cannot display when called with R CMD BATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730175/gwidgets-gui-cannot-display-when-called-with-r-cmd-batch)
Also similar to this one: https://thesquareplanet.com/blog/interactive-r-scripts/
Still not sure how to implement.

The difference is, I would like to know how I can set the `Rexec` file to automatically run interactively, instead of running it from the command line with an extra argument every time?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use `cat()` and have your message in the terminal?

Comment: @KhatamNaayak There is no error, just no dialog box popping up.

Comment: @Michael I'm avoiding anything in the terminal, as I need a nice GUI which doesn't require looking at any code to know when it has finished running.

Comment: To verify that problem is with winDialog(), can you check executing a simple winDialog("ok", "some message") or winDialogString("Some message", "Default Message") and share output?

Comment: @KhatamNaayak I've done this, and I just realised that there is an error, but as soon as the error is shown the window closes itself. I'm looking at this problem but I cannot find a solution. *Edit: I have run it and tried to catch the error in a screenshot, and I am getting 
"winDialog() cannot be used non-interactively 
Exec"

Comment: May I know which version of R you are using?

Comment: @KhatamNaayak R 3.4.0, and the executable file is using RScript.exe

Comment: @KhatamNaayak It appears my question is similar to this one:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730175/gwidgets-gui-cannot-display-when-called-with-r-cmd-batch. 

How would I implement this without using the command line every time, just by changing one setting and double-clicking the file?