# How to implement this solution to make R scripts interactive?

Tags: r, shell

I have found this answer to a problem I had discussed previously here: [How to get dialog/message box working in executable R file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274613/how-to-get-dialog-message-box-working-in-executable-r-file)

The answer is here:
https://thesquareplanet.com/blog/interactive-r-scripts/

Specifically this bit:

```
We can use this to provide an interactive R script executor in /usr/local/bin/Rint: #!/bin/sh f=$1; shift; env "R_PROFILE_USER=$f" "ARGS=$@" R --no-save -q
```

My problem is that I know nothing about the command prompt or batch files. So what does this line mean, and do I just paste it into the command prompt once and then add "#!/usr/local/bin/Rint" to the top of my executable R script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is not for a Windows cmd.exe shell. This is for a UNIX/Linux shell.

We can use this to provide an interactive R script executor in /usr/local/bin/Rint:

```
#!/bin/sh
f=$1;
shift;
env "R_PROFILE_USER=$f" "ARGS=$@"
R --no-save -q
```

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted your answer. Do you know if there is a way to do this on Windows 10?

Comment: I do not know R well enough to know if this can be done on Windows. I would remove the `cmd` and `windows` tags and add the `shell` tag.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking, this is the best resource I can find about executable R GUIs in Windows:

http://oddhypothesis.blogspot.com.au/2014/04/deploying-self-contained-r-apps-to.html

Still working through this tutorial, will update if it answers the question.